# Fetching previous days news from google news

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-news

I am using the following link to fetch news: http://news.google.com/news?ned=in&topic=h&output=rss.
This url will not be changing daily. So how can I get the previous days news form this link? I am using JavaScript to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I think this one may work:

http://news.google.com/news?ned=in&topic=h&output=rss&as_mind=3&as_maxm=2&as_qdr=2

Try check this page:

http://blog.slashpoundbang.com/post/12975232033/google-news-search-parameters-the-missing-manual

Comment: Unfortunately it seems that date parameters are not supported anymore :(

Comment: And that post is dead